# Passing const pointers by ref is better than by value?

Tags: c++

When passing a parameter representing a constant buffer of data, is it best to pass by ref? For example a string could be passed as `const char * const` indicating that both the pointer and the content are constant.

But would `const char * const &` be better? I have recently seen material stating that passing const values by value is misleading since a copy is made anyway, so in a perverse way passing the `const` pointer by val would be misleading? If the pointer is to be `const` it should be passed by ref and therefore `const char * const &` would be best?

Comment: You seem to be confused between C++ where there are references denoted by `&` and C where there are no references denoted by `&`.

Comment: Apologies, should I re-post wih a c++ tag?

Comment: @Peter You can edit your question and replace the C tag with C++

Comment: @peter: No need to repost. You can change the tags on your post (This was already done by msam, in this case).

Comment: My question is directed at const correctness. If a parameter is declared as const int x then some may object to the const since x is passed by value. Even if the function did alter x the caller would never see the new value for x. The const may be considered superflous. One might use const int &x. But then does the same apply to a pointer that is const and cannot be reallocated? Instead of int * const x would one not use const * const &x?

Comment: "Instead of int * const x would one not use const * const &x?" ...no, they are not equivalent. In the first one the value of x can be modified, see edit to my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

`const char* const x` means x is a constant pointer to a constant char

`const char* const & x` means that x is a reference to a constant pointer to a constant char

The first one passes the pointer, the second a reference to the pointer. In terms of possible use within the function in both cases x acts as a read-only char pointer.

EDIT in response to OP'S comment:
you might be mixing up const correctness and advantages of passing by reference.

`const int* x` (equivalent to `int const* x`) is a pointer to a constant int, the value of the int cannot be changed through the pointer. In other words you can do `x = (int*)y` (value of x will change only in the scope of function) but not `*x = 1`.

`const int& x` (equivalent to `int const& x`) means x is a reference to a constant int. You cannot do `x = 1`

`const int x` means that x is a const int. This basically amounts to x being read only. x is a copy of another int so if we remove the `const` and modify `x` it would only be modified within the scope of the function. I do not see why someone would object to the const in this case. This is used to avoid programming mistakes like assigning x to some other value then using it again having forgotten about the change in value.

Using `const int& x` instead of `const int x` only makes sense if x is an object to avoid making a copy. For the same purpose we could also use `const int* const x`.

Using `const int* const &x` instead of `const int* const x` has the same effect but there are caveats. For instance, if you do this, `x` can be null! This in itself can be confusing since normally you would expect a value passed by reference to be guaranteed to be non-null. However in this case the reference can be to a null-pointer which would result in an exception if we try to dereference. Dereferencing a null pointer, of course, also results in an exception but this is well-known. As yet I do not see any advantage whatsoever of using `const int* const &x`.

`int * const x` is **not** equivalent to `const * const &x`. `int * const x` means that the pointer is const, but we can change the value of x (ie we can do `*x = 3`)

Comment: Thanks masam and Mushy. I'm going to try to answer this myself, but I am looking for some guidance here.

Answer (score 0):

When passing by `reference`, as you stated, no copy is supplied as an argument but rather is bound through the reference.

It is important to understand that reference parameters that are not changed inside a function should be references to `const`.

A common mistake programmers make is to define parameters that a function does not change as `plain old references`.  However, doing so will give the functions's caller the misleading impression that the function might change its argument's value.  It is better to use a `reference to const`, where applicable, because a `plain reference` unduly limits the type of arguments that can be used with the function.

Where applicable because if you desire to change the argument then it should **not** have a `const reference parameter`.

Also, similar to a`reference to const`, a `pointer to const` says nothing about whether the object to which the pointer points is `const`.  Defining a pointer to `const` only affects what we can do with the pointer.

There is also the notion of `top-level const` and `low-level const` with respect to pointers.  A `top-level const` indicates the pointer itself is a `const`whereas if a pointer points to a `const`, that `const` pointed to is referred to as a `low-level const`.